# Zend framework - Run something after the execution of a model

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a generic model called MyWork_Model_Base that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract. All my models then extend MyWork_Model_Base. Is there a way I can add a code to this Model_Base so that it runs every time after the model function is executed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the code to the `__destruct` function of the `MyWork_Model_Base` class. The destructor will be executed every time the function is executed

```
class Model_User extends MyWork_Model_Base
{

    public function getUserDetails()
    {
        $select = $this->select();

        $this->column = 'user_id';
        $this->value = '9999';

        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }

}



class MyWork_Model_Base extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
  .
  .
  .
  public function fetchAll($select)
  {
    return parent::fetchAll($select);
  }
  public function __destruct()
  {
    echo 'Destruct Called : '.$this->column.'//'.$this->value.' <br/>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this __destruct() also find out the $row or at least the id of the row that was modified/created/deleted or do I need to pass it that information?

Comment: You can set the value in the function that is been executed and use it in the __destruct

Comment: As it have a variable $_id and save that in the function, and call $this->_id in the __destruct()?

Comment: yes... i have updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for?